# Is there a way to search users by externalid using the googleapis/google-api-python-client library?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-api-python-client

I am writing a python application that uses the Google Admin SDK to search for users in the user directory. I need to search users by the External ID or the Employee ID, it doesn't seem to be implemented in the python library (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client#installation), but there is support from google as it says in their official docs, see (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users#examples)

I would really appreciate it if someone can help point things out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

*It is possible to search for user by the external Id using the query parameter `query`.*

### Step by step

1. Check the [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python)
2. Use the method [users.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list)
3. Define the customer. You can use `my_customer`
4. Define your [query](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users). Example: `query = 'externalId:someValue'`
5. [Get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/get) the users that match the result of the `list`

### Code

```py
results = service.users().list( customer='my_customer',
                                query='externalId:someValue',
                                orderBy='email'
                                ).execute()
users = results.get('users', [])
```

### References

- [Admin SDK: Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python)
- [Admin SDK: users.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list)
- [Admin SDK: users.get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/get)
- [Search for users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users)